# How to handle functions after dom change

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I'm having alot of ajax calls where every one of them insert new html code into the DOM.In ajax on success I'm calling functions again so they have the option to work with the new DOM elements.
The problem is that whit every new call the functions on success gets called X times - 1,2,4... And for example if I have a function createNewButton and click it twice I'll end up with 3 buttons, because the second time it pass the ajax will call the function again.

```
function ajaxAddFormFeild(field_type, value, unique) {
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function (request)
        {
            request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
        },
        type: "GET",
        url: base_url + 'Form/' + field_type + '?value=' + value + '&unique=' + unique,
        success: function (response) {
            if (unique) {
                $('.input-options[data-unique="' + unique + '"').first().after(response);
            } else {
                $('.form_content').append(response);
                addNewOption();
                changeFormFieldPosition();
            }
            removeFormGroup();
            removeFormField();
        },
        dataType: 'html'
    });
}
```

Im building server side generated form builder.
What will be the perfect realization ?!
You click minuses without giving an answer...

Comment: Some code please. You're probably attaching a listener after every AJAX call.

Comment: you should provide codes you have tried

Comment: Yes Im attaching them,if I not they will be not working for the new elements.But when they are attached twice or more... gets called each one over another.

Comment: Show me the code where you're attaching listeners.

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery method `$().off()` to unbind the event on that element which is invoking the ajaxCall function repeatedly.

Comment: That won't solve the problem but remove the consequences.